# Mongodb Mapreduce average where group by

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, where-clause, average

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("529e2a982d296ef0d40938c3"),
"date" : NumberLong(19541012),
"element" : "PRCP",
"id" : "IN024141500",
"lcol" : "",
"mflag1" : "",
"qflag1" : "",
"sflag1" : "I",
"value1" : 0,
"year" : 1954
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("529e39642d296ef0d435c197"),
"date" : NumberLong(19570105),
"element" : "TMAX",
"id" : "IN024141500",
"lcol" : "",
"mflag1" : "",
"qflag1" : "",
"sflag1" : "S",
"value1" : 272,
"year" : 1957
}
```

How would I calculate the average for value1 grouped by year field where element field is PRCP?

I know aggregation in mongodb doesn't allow avg and group by. So, How can I do it using mapreduce. 
Or is there a better option to do this?

Comment: You don't need map-reduce for this as `aggregate` _does_ support `$avg` and `$group`.

Comment: does it also support where clause with $avg and $group?

Comment: Sure, that's what the `$match` operator is for.  Docs [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/).

Comment: db.IN024141500.aggregate(
                        {$match: {element: "TMAX"}},
                        {$group: {_id: "$year",average: {$avg: "$value1"}}})

<br>
This query give me error:
uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
 "errmsg" : "no such cmd: aggregate",
 "bad cmd" : {
  "aggregate" : "IN024141500",
  "pipeline" : [
   {
    "$match" : {
     "element" : "TMAX"
    }
   },
   {
    "$group" : {
     "_id" : "$year",
     "average" : {
      "$avg" : "$value1"
     }
    }
   }
  ]
 },
 "ok" : 0
}

Comment: The `aggregate` command was introduced in MongoDB v2.2, so if you're not at that version or later you'll need to upgrade.

Comment: You are right. I had an older version. I upgraded mongodb and it works like a charm. Thank You